# How to make this vector animation?

Tags: video, animation

I would like to make a demonstration animation like this...

As I am really ignorant about animation making, I even don't know how to describe it.  I think this is something made with vector, as you see there are zooming effects.

I think this animation is made very practical. I hope I could master it in minimum time. Anybody would tell me what technology is used and how long could a beginner master it.

Answer (score 1):

That is the realm of motion graphics and is probably using vector graphics within the motion graphics.  To get something of that quality, would take a very long time for a beginner to make look that good, though if someone is naturally skilled at it, it could shorten the curve considerably.  It requires skill in multiple disciplines to produces a reasonably high production value video like that.

If you want to try to pursue it though, I would suggest looking at software like Flash or After Effects.  Illustrator is also worth looking at for developing the vector assets.  After Effects with Illustrator is probably the best bet as it supports 3d layers (which could be used for the 3D spinning) as well as fairly easy support for write on text.  The painting effect is probably a little easier in Flash, but should be plenty doable with some work in After Effects.

Your early work isn't going to look anything like the video you linked though.  If you want such a video for commercial purposes, your best bet is to pay a studio to do something for you.  If you just want to play around, then dig in to the topic of Motion Graphics which is way too big of a topic to cover in one question and answer.

Comment: Well, thanks for you guys who edited and answered my question. Actually I am a university teacher to give lessons in computer science. There are too many complex concepts to illustrate in class and it would be very helpful to give impression on students if a demonstration could be played like this. I would like to ask you to have a basic judgement whether a teacher, in computer science of course, could accomplish this workload to make this kind of motion graphics.

Comment: @user43312 - yeah, certainly for a demonstration like that, it would be much simpler.  You wouldn't need nearly the production value, but the software involved is still reasonably pricey (though academic pricing isn't nearly as bad.)  Which concepts in particular are you trying to demonstrate?  (I'm actually a software architect by trade with a dual major in the electronic arts side of things. :) )  What you could make wouldn't look as polished, but it could certainly convey the point if you have some natural abilities in electronic arts.

Comment: Your resume is really amazing. I am giving lessons on Linux Shell and the reference textbook is *Linux Command Line and Shell Scripting Bible* by Richard Blum and Christine Bresnahan. What I want to demonstrate is the four functionalities of kernel, ie, the management of memory/software/hardware/filesystem. The concepts are weigh too abstract without a metaphor or a demonstration. For example, the *Virtual Momery* is actually a mapped scenary seen by the kernel from both the *Physical Memory* and the *Swap Space*. A motion graphic will show the process of this mapping perfectly.

Comment: @user43312 - yeah, I think you should be able to do that easily with either Flash or After Effects.  Both are available under academic license from Adobe.  If you want to represent things as blocks, you can make some simple visualizations for memory segments with squares and then put them in groups to allow you to manipulate them as a group.  It should just be a matter of using keyframe animation to bring them to the positions you want when you want and then using another keyframe to move them away when you need to.  It should be pretty simple for you.

Comment: OK. I'll give it a try on that. Thanks for your guide.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the logo with some design software for vertorial drawing like Ilustrator. Then you need yo animate this in another software like After Effects. Its very simple. You only need to set some keys in each frame number changing XYZ coordinates of rotation and traslation. Then you can add motion blur to smooth the animation. Thats all.

Comment: Those key points you gave is very helpful. Thank you very much, Abraham.